# Mono flatmap body runs twice

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have a java service.
Service receives a message, enriches it, stores it in a database, and sends it to kafka.

The service is made of reactive streams, DAO layer made of jdbc.

**Controller:**

```
@Api @Slf4j @Validated
@RestController
@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class IncomingMessageController {

    private final IncomingMessageProcessingService processingService;

    @PostMapping(value = "/incoming")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> handleIncomingMessages(
            @RequestBody VkIncomingMessage message
    ) {
        
         return processingService.processMessage(message)
                .then(Mono.just(ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .body("ok")));
    }
}
```

**Processing Service:**

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
public class IncomingMessageProcessingService {

    private final List<IncomingMessageProcessor> incomingMessageProcessors;

    public IncomingMessageProcessingService(
            Optional<LoggingIncomingMessageProcessor> loggingIncomingMessageProcessor,
            Optional<SendToKafkaIncomingMessageProcessor> kafkaIncomingMessageProcessor
    ) {
        incomingMessageProcessors = new ArrayList<>();
        loggingIncomingMessageProcessor.ifPresent(this.incomingMessageProcessors::add);
        kafkaIncomingMessageProcessor.ifPresent(this.incomingMessageProcessors::add);
    }

    public Mono<VkIncomingDto> processMessage(VkIncomingMessage vkIncomingMessage) {

        var vkIncomingDto = MessageMappingUtils.toVkIncomingDto(vkIncomingMessage);
        var vkIncomingDtoMono = Mono.just(vkIncomingDto);
        for (var processor : incomingMessageProcessors) {
            vkIncomingDtoMono = processor.processIncomingMessage(vkIncomingDtoMono);
        }
        return vkIncomingDtoMono;
    }
}
```

**LoggingIncomingMessageProcessor:**

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
@ConditionalOnProperty(
        name = {"toggle.logging-incoming-processor"},
        havingValue = "true",
        matchIfMissing = true)
public class LoggingIncomingMessageProcessor
        implements IncomingMessageProcessor {

    private final IncomingMessagesDao incomingMessagesDao;
    private final MessagesDao messagesDao;
    private final IdGenerator idGenerator;

    @Override
    public Mono<VkIncomingDto> processIncomingMessage(Mono<VkIncomingDto> vkIncomingDtoMono) {
        return vkIncomingDtoMono
                .flatMap(vkIncomingDto -> {

                    var originalMsgOutLogin = getOriginalMsgOutLogin(Long.parseLong(vkIncomingDto.vkIncoming.getObject()
                            .getMessage()
                            .getMessageTag()));

                    var enrichedIncomingMessage = enrichVkIncomingMessages(vkIncomingDto, originalMsgOutLogin);
                    incomingMessagesDao.insert(enrichedIncomingMessage);
                    return Mono.just(enrichedIncomingMessage);
                });
    }

    private VkIncomingDto enrichVkIncomingMessages(VkIncomingDto vkIncomingDto, String login) {
        return vkIncomingDto.toBuilder()
                .id(idGenerator.getNext())
                .vkMessageId(Long.parseLong(Objects.requireNonNull(
                        vkIncomingDto.vkIncoming.getObject().getMessage().getMessageTag())))
                .login(login)
                .build();
    }

    private String getOriginalMsgOutLogin(Long originalMsgOutId) {
        return messagesDao.getLoginToIdMap(Set.of(originalMsgOutId)).get(originalMsgOutId);
    }
}
```

**SendToKafkaIncomingMessageProcessor:**

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Repository
@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
@ConditionalOnProperty(
        name = {"toggle.kafka-incoming-processor", "server.providermode"},
        havingValue = "true",
        matchIfMissing = true)
public class SendToKafkaIncomingMessageProcessor implements IncomingMessageProcessor {

    private final VkIncomingMessageProducer messageProducer;

    @Override
    public Mono<VkIncomingDto> processIncomingMessage(Mono<VkIncomingDto> vkIncomingDtoMono) {

        return vkIncomingDtoMono
                .flatMap(vkIncomingDto -> messageProducer.sendMessage(MessageMappingUtils.toIncomingMessage(vkIncomingDto)))
                .then(vkIncomingDtoMono);
    }
}
```

I need to return an enriched message from LoggingIncomingMessageProcessor in order to send this information to Kafka.
The problem is that the code inside flatMap is run twice, resulting in 2 records being saved to the database and 1 message being sent to kafka.

Comment: im not going to answer your question, but im going to tell you that you are coding imperative (regular java) using for-loops etc. in a reactive environment. And your dto calls are not returning Monos or Fluxes which tells me that they probably are blocking calls. Just placing things in `Mono.just` doesn't make things reactive. Also your code is way too abstract for us to know or even run your code, you should instead produce a minimal example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: we have no idea what your `processors` do or your `util` classes do or what your `dto` classes do etc etc.

Comment: I believe that the code is completely non-blocking, except of the DAO layer, as I wrote, it is implemented on JDBC, not on R2DBC. Not returning mono or flux on dto calls does not make the code blocking.

Comment: You are aware that JDBC is blocking? And that when performing things outside the reactive context doesn’t allow the reactive framework to optimize its thread usage to give you fully reactive behaviour. Just one single blocking call in a non-blocking application can seriously cripple your entire application. So your belief is faulty and you should read up on the reactor architecture and why blocking is bad.

Comment: `Not returning mono or flux on dto calls does not make the code blocking.` is completely wrong, because every call needs to wait until the concrete value is returned. We cant return a value if it doesnt exist. Thats what Mono and Fluxes are for to, to return ”something” and signal when the value is available

Comment: Of course. But my question is why is the LoggingIncomingMessageProcessor.processMessage code inside the flatMap body being run twice. If this behavior is due to the blocking nature of JDBC, I'd like to understand why.

Comment: and as i wrote above, your code is way too abstract, i cant run your code.

Comment: I can't see any obvious reason why it could run twice but I'd suggest not to pass Mono objects as method parameters, rather just pass around the dto object as it is. Passing around a Mono can easily lead to multiple subscriptions and multiple unintended executions.